# C# xamarin.forms: Async and Await use not working in my code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I will appreciate some help with the below code.

Using C# in Xamarin forms for a simple new app.

I have one page after you created your club and displaying the list of members.

Click to add, new page will be displayed with only a `text entry` and a `done button`. When the `done` is clicked, `PopAsync()` is called back and the new member is created and added to the list.

I have handled the `null exception` (I think correctly) - I can't figure out *why null entries are still throwing an exception*, code is here (this is handled from the first page.

Apologies if the question is too noob:

```
async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var page = new NewClub3();
        await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        page.Addbutton.Clicked += async (source, args) =>
        {
            if (page.NameEntry.Text.ToString() == null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Oops", "Please enter a name.", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                newMembers.Add(new User(page.NameEntry.Text.ToString()));
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: use String.IsNullOrEmpty(page.NameEntry.Text) to check for a null/empty string.    NameEntry.Text is a string, so calling ToString() on it is not needed

Comment: Thanks Jason, IsNullOrEmpty solved it. exception was thrown at the if statement due to the unnecessary ToString() call on a null string.

Answer (score 3):

Used

string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(page.NameEntry.Text)

instead of

page.NameEntry.Text.ToString() == null